# Single variable Integration word problem

Tags: calculus, integration

In 2000 the yearly world petroleum consumption was about 77 billion barrels and the yearly exponential rate of increase in use was 2%. How many years after 2000 are the world's total estimated oil reserves of 1020 billion barrels likely to last?

What I did was I set up an Integral bounded from 0 to n with the integrand as 77(1.02)^t dt, and I got roughly 11.76, however my textbook has the integrand set as 77e^(0.02t) which I don't understand why they set it as. Sorry for the bad formatting, somewhat new to mathstackexchange.

I don't understand why the textbook would use e^(0.02t) since exponential increase is a(1+r)^t if I am not mistaken

Comment: Do you understand the difference between interest compounded annually for $t$ years and interest compounded *continuously* for $t$ years? They are assuming *continuous* petroleum consumption.

Answer (score 1):

- It is the same formula. $77(1.02)^t=77e^{.02t}$.  You are correct that exponential growth is of the form $a(1+r)^t$. You can convert between the forms $ae^{kt}=a\left(1+r\right)^{t}$ via $k=\ln(1+r)$. For this problem, $k=\ln1.02\approx0.0198$ or about .02. Then $77(1.02)^{t}=77e^{.02t}$.
- However, I am unsure about integrating. Are you sure you're supposed to integrate? Just set $77e^{.02t}=1020\Rightarrow t=129.19$ years.